# iOS 7 javascript XMLHttpRequest bug

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, ios7

This post is half question - half announcement..  i develop iOS applications which include UIWebView that performs javascript code.
When i run the app on devices with the newly iOS 7, some of the functionality doesn't work.
after long debugging, i have managed to isolate the reason.
Javascript AJAX has a request API with the constructor method open :

> XMLHttpRequest.open(method,url,async)

'asynch' argument is false if the call should be blocking and true otherwise.
the problem **on iOS 7 safari only** is that this method throws exception if 'async' is false.

so, hope this would help to any of you encountering the same problem, and if anyone can shad a light about this bug or way to work around it it would be great

Thanks!

Comment: I believe they pulled the ability to make synchronous calls awhile back.

Comment: **Don't.** You should avoid synchronous http requests as much as possible. What if the user is on a super-slow network and your request locks the application for 4-8 seconds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The UIWebview does not allow synchronous XHRs in IOS7.

This is one of the frustrating differences between the WebView and Safari (which does allow them).

The workaround:

1. Create an Objective-C function that makes a [synchronous HTTP request](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_6).
2. [Call that function from JavaScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html). (This happens synchronously.)

Of course, if you wanted any benefits like caching, you would have to implement that yourself.

It's a bit baffling why Apple would think requiring that workaround is a good idea.

Comment: this is indeed the problem and the appropriate solution. Thanks